# How to Return Date using date range, and include anything older than a defined number of days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query where i'm attempting to pull data from a transaction table that is between a date range, or 60 days Older than the start date.

Here is what I mean.

Data in the table:

```
select *
from Transactions

Created       TransactionID
12/1/16           1
12/5/16          2
1/1/15           3
3/1/16           4
4/1/16           5
4/2/16           6
4/3/16           7
```

What I'd like to do, is return the data between 4/1 and 4/4.  OR anything 60 days older than 4/1.  So the output should be:

```
12/1/16           1
12/5/16          2
1/1/16           3
4/1/16           5
4/2/16           6
4/3/16           7
```

It should leave out 3/1/16 because it's not older than 60 days.

I thought initially I could use DateDiff - But that just bumps the start date out 60 days.

```
Select *
From Transactions
where created between Datediff(dd,-60,@startdate) and @enddate
```

This returns, and I know why:

```
3/1/16           4
4/1/16           5
4/2/16           6
4/3/16           7
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Use `dateadd` and subtract 60 days from the @startdate.
2) Use `or` for your conditions.

```
Select *
From Transactions
where created < dateadd(dd,-60,@startdate) 
or created between '2016-04-01' and '2016-04-04'
```

Comment: Erm.  I obviously was overthinking this.  That's for the help!